# How to link external JS function with HTML button click

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, onclick

I just strated with cordova project. In my HTML there is a button and i want to add click event for that. Click event function is written in external JS file. But unfortunately the function is not getting called. Given below is my HTML and JS files. please help me

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  app.initialize();
  </script>
    <div>
     <h1 id="login">Login</h1>
     <div class="label_edit">
       <div  type="label"; id = "username_lbl"  class="label">USERNAME
       <input type="text"; id = "username_edit" class="edit" />
       </div> 

     </div>
     <div class="label_edit">
       <div  type="label"; id = "password_lbl"  class="label">PASSWORD
       <input type="password"; id = "password_edit"  class="edit"/>
       </div> 
     </div>
     <br/>
     <input type="button" value="submit" id="login_submit" onclick="submitBtnFunc();"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    app.submitBtnFunc(id);
},
function submitBtnFunc(id)
{
  alert("user name is :");
  var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
  alert(username);
 }
```

};

Comment: You are declaring the function **submitBtnFunc** in a wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, your function declaration is wrong. You can't declare a member function like that.

Change:

```
function submitBtnFunc(id)
{
  alert("user name is :");
  var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
  alert(username);
}
```

To:

```
submitBtnFunc: function(id)
{
  alert("user name is :");
  var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
  alert(username);
}
```

Also, I haven't used Cordova, so I might be missing something here, but, the `submitBtnFunc` seems to be in the object stored in the variable `app` so you need to specify `app.submitBtnFunc`, also you aren't passing through a value for the `id` parameter.

Try this for the button instead:

```
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="login_submit" onclick="app.submitBtnFunc('idvalue');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `submitBtnFunc` has to be out of var `app` initialization, or has to be declared as var `app` method.

Out of initialization:

```
var app = {

        ...
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
function submitBtnFunc(id)
{
    alert("user name is :");
    var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
    alert(username);
}
```

and

```
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="login_submit" onclick="submitBtnFunc('login_submit');"/>
```

As `app` method:

```
var app = {

        ...

        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    submitBtnFunc: function(id)
    {
        alert("user name is :");
        var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
        alert(username);
    }
};
```

and

```
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="login_submit" onclick="app.submitBtnFunc('login_submit');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function inside a literal object like this :

```
   var literalObject ={

        fun1 : function (){
          //here goes your implementation 
        },
        fun2 : function (){
          //here goes your implementation 
        },

    }
```

and you call it by

```
     literalObject.fun1();
```

In your case :

```
        var app ={
        ....
        ....
        ....
         , submitBtnFunc : function (id)
           {
         alert("user name is :");
         var username = document.getElementById("username_edit").value;
         alert(username);
          },
        ....
        ....
        ....
        }
```

and you bind it to onclick event on the button like this:

```
       <input type="button" value="submit" id="login_submit" onclick="app.submitBtnFunc('someId');"/>
```

Welcome ;)